# Вопрос по системе комментирование Disqus

Tags: php, modx, комментарии, disqus

Хочу прикрутить на сайт комментарии disqus(сайт на modx). Подскажите, возможно ли сделать так, чтобы комментарии оставленные через эту систему записывались в бд сайта и выводились комментарии в общем стиле сайта, а не disqus.
Например, есть такой скриншот:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Здесь сверху идут комментарии сайта(фейковые), а комментарии disqus идут отдельно. Как сделать так, чтобы комментарии выводились так же как и фейковые, а в интерфейсе disqus они не появлялись?

Comment: А... зачем вам тогда Disqus вообще?

Comment: @D-side чтобы не писать свою регистрацию на сайте, так как она нужна только для комментирование 1 страницы( в виде отзывов )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Да, в этом случае тебе надо реализовать их самостоятельную отрисовку.

1. Алгоритм такой , форма дискуса остается такая же,
2. Пишешь граббер, который через API получает их комментарии
3. Отображаешь комментарии из БД

Подробнее можно почитать в оф. документации 
https://help.disqus.com/customer/portal/articles/472125-data-synchronization